# Can't run basic websocket on remote tomcat

Tags: tomcat, java-websocket

[image]I'm trying to run a basic websocket example. I made a java class with a @ServerEndpoint annotation and it's working fine if running on a localhost, with a tomcat running in Eclipse.

But when I export it to a war file and deploy it on a remote tomcat, I can't get it to work. As soon as I connect, it disconnect with in console:

```
WebSocket connection to' ws://192.168.70.156:8080/.../notifications' failed
```

If i log in the onclose method, I have a 1006 error code.
If in my test page I replace the remote address by localhost, it works fine on my local tomcat.

The remote url is correct (i can access to the tomcat manager and the war is deployed), I have no error in the catalina log and the extracted structure of the remote webapps folder is exactly the same as the one extracted in my local tomcat.

Do someone have any idea of what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see you are using Safari. Does that happen to be version 15? Evidently, Safari 15 just doesn't do Websocket properly. Try running the [autobahn test suite](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-testsuite) against it and you may find that Safari is just broken. Can you re-try your tests using Chrome of Firefox?

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Safary. My problem is the same with Chrome/Edge/Firefox. Probably something missing in the dependencies cause it works well if running in local Eclipse...

Comment: There seems to be some more details about that failed connection, if you expand the `>` to the left of the error message. Maybe the browser is telling you exactly what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing relevant, just the client stacktrace. I finaly made my server with NodeJs instead of tomcat and it's running fine. I didn't understand what was wrong....

Comment: Sounds like you've given up. If you're willing to provide details, perhaps Tomcat can be made to work.